# Why IDs of the same bound method of the same object are equal?

Tags: python

Recently I saw several questions about unexpected behavior when performing `is` test on the same bound method of the same object. Specifically, please see questions [Why does `instance_of_object.foo is instance_of_object.foo` evaluate False?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50498770) and [Two methods inherited from one method in class are different in instances, aren't they?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48736670)

Let's describe the issue, for example, as described in the first linked question above. Let's assume a class:

```
class A(object):
  def foo(self):
    pass
```

Then the strange thing observed in that question is that if we create an object of type `A` such as `a = A()` then test `a.foo is a.foo` fails (returns `False`). According to answer given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48736729, a new `method` instance is created every time a bound method is accessed.

If that is correct and explains why `a.foo is a.foo` is always `False`, why the`id`s of these presumably distinct `method` objects are equal:

```
>>> id(a.foo) == id(a.foo)
True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're wrestling with illusions ;-)  In

```
id(a.foo) == id(a.foo)
```

the first `a.foo` is created, its `id` is obtained, and then the bound method immediately becomes garbage.  In `CPython`, reference counting causes its memory to be freed at once.  The same memory happens to be reused (although there's no *guarantee* this will happen) when the second `a.foo` is created.  `id`s are only guaranteed unique across a collection of objects *simultaneously* alive.

In contrast, in

```
a.foo is a.foo
```

both sides are simultaneously alive, so the distinct `a.foo` objects cannot occupy the same memory.  To do a similar thing with `id`s, you have to arrange to keep keep both of them alive long enough for the `id` comparison to complete; e.g.,

```
>>> a1 = a.foo
>>> id(a1) == id(a.foo)
False
```

Comment: Eh, my bad. I missed this. Thanks!

Comment: No worries!  Bona fide Python experts have been tricked by this too :-)